# How to make sidebar and filter in Product-Category Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am newbie in woocommerce.

Currently, I am using the GreatStore theme in Wordpress.
And I am trying to make filter by size of the tablet on the top and make sidebar. 
But I do not know how to do that and the theme seems no offer for that. (No sidebar widget in product-category page)
Can anyone tell me how can I make those in Product-category page?

This is the page: http://dev.myhexa.com/product-category/Windows/

Thanks,

Comment: i think you don't need any code level changes for this. just go to wordpress dashboard.
Appearance -> widgets  and you will find a widget for filter and then place it on shop sidebar widget place which definitely exist.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to override the current product category page.

Create a new file `taxonomy-product_cat.php`.

For reference -

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files/

https://www.woothemes.com/2014/08/five-quick-woocommerce-customization-tips/